# CSS rule mysteriously vanishes

Tags: css

In [this page](http://new.und.edu/), I have the following rule in [ui.css](http://new.und.edu/_files/scripts/ui.css):

```
.cfl #home-columns .col li:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

It's supposed to move the "more" link at the bottom of each of the four columns to the bottom of the shared container.

The problem is that the rule is being discarded by browsers.  If you look at the live CSS through Firebug (or Chrome's dev tools, or IE's, or Opera's Dragonfly), the rule just isn't there.  Yet if I enter the *exact* same rule directly in Firebug, it works fine.

I ran the CSS file through the W3C validator ([results](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnew.und.edu%2F_files%2Fscripts%2Fui.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)) and with the exception of a bunch of vendor-prefixed properties, everything checks out.

Color me puzzled.  What am I missing?

EDIT:

At @Jason Gennaro's suggestion, I tried putting it in a different CSS file and loading that. It works fine when I put it in another CSS file.  There's just something weird going on with ui.css.  So, I could fix my problem by adding yet another stylesheet.  I'd really rather avoid that, though, since the site already has fourteen CSS files, which is moderately ridiculous.

EDIT 2:

[image: screenshot of three file states, further description below]

Here's a screenshot of the various states, showing the file as viewed directly in a browser, the CSS as shown in Chrome's live developer tools view, and the file as downloaded via wget from an off-site (non-web-server) linux box.

EDIT 3:

The problem was that a load balancer had a cached copy of the stylesheet for HTTPS only. So the fix is to get the stupid load balancer fixed.

Comment: have you tried placing that `rule` in another stylesheet to see what happens?

Comment: @Jason No I haven't, good suggestion, I'll try it and report back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see ui.css loaded anywhere. Are you sure you're loading the file?

Comment: Good thought, but yes, it's loaded through an @import directive in screen.css (line 30).

Comment: Ok, found it. Thanks. Now I can't find your rule in that file. Do you have the line number for it?

Comment: It's at line 48.  EDIT: and you may need to refresh your copy of the CSS file, I uploaded a fresh one a couple of minutes ago and it's cached.

Comment: I've emptied my cache and refreshed the page. I'm still not seeing the rule. Here's a screenshot of what I see at line 48: http://cl.ly/8EZG . It's also not in the file if I browse directly to it.

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing: http://www.libsys.und.edu/dev/bizarro-css.png

Comment: @Will, it looks like there are inconsistent duplicates of this file, one at **http**://new.und.edu/_files/scripts/ui.css and the other at **https**://library.und.edu/_files/scripts/ui.css The @import for ui.css is bringing in the file from the encrypted protocol, while the rule is in the unencrypted protocol.

Comment: AAARGH!  I bet it's that stupid load balancer.

Comment: @Will, you can change the @import to the http:// ui.css and it should work.

Comment: Ordinarily you'd be right, but doing so would break SSL connections to all the other pages on the site, for reasons which make my head hurt. I'll just have to talk with ITSS about it. Thanks for the debugging, you've been a great help!